fractional ideals and localizations of finitely generated modules

Suppose $R$ is an integral domain with fraction field $K$ and $A$ is a fractional ideal of $R$ in $K$. Let $A' = \{\,x \in K \,|\, x A \subseteq R\,\}$ as in Proposition 9.
(a) For any prime ideal $P$ in $R$ prove that the localization $(A')_P$ of $A'$ at $P$ is a fractional ideal of $R_P$ in $K$.
(b) If $A$ is a finitely generated $R$-module, prove that $(A')_P = (A_P)'$ where $(A_P)'$ is the fractional $R_p$ ideal $\{\,x \in K \,|\, x A_P \subseteq R_P\,\}$ corresponding to the localization $A_P$.

Let $D:=R\setminus P$. I have proved (a).
For part (b), let $A=\sum_{i=1}^na_iR$ for some $a_i\in K=\mathrm{Frac}(R)$ by assumption. I have shown that $(A')_P\subseteq(A_P)'$, namely $D^{-1}(A')\subseteq(D^{-1}A)'$, by using the condition that $A$ is a finitely generated $R$-module.
For the converse, let $x\in(D^{-1}A)'=\{\,x \in K \,|\, x A_P \subseteq R_P\,\}$, then
$$
\begin{gather*}
 xD^{-1}A\subseteq D^{-1}R
 \\\Rightarrow\ \ \forall\,\frac{a}{d_1}\in\frac AD,\ \exists\,\frac{r}{d_2}\in\frac RD\ \text{s.t.}\ x\frac{a}{d_1}=\frac{r}{d_2}
 \\\Rightarrow\ \ d_2xa=d_1r\in R.
\end{gather*}
$$
Hence let $\delta:=\prod_{d\in D}d$, then $d_2xa=d_1r\in R$ provides that $\delta xa=(\delta/d_2)d_2xa=\big(\prod_{d\in D\setminus\{d_2\}}d\big)d_1r\in R$, so $\delta xA\subseteq R\ \Rightarrow\ \delta x\in A'\ \Rightarrow\ x\in A'/\delta\subseteq A'/D$, as desired.
But in this proof, I am not sure whether the choice of $\delta:=\prod_{d\in D}d$ is valid or not: we usually take only finite product, but $\delta$ is infinite product.

Update: thanks for @Aditya Dwivedi's help, I solve my doubt: my proof has not used the condition that $A$ is finitely generated, and my proof is wrong. Let me give a new one with respect to Aditya Dwivedi's answer.
Recall that $(D^{-1}A)'=\{\,x \in\mathrm{Frac}(R) \,|\, xD^{-1}A \subseteq D^{-1}R\,\}$ and that $A=\sum_{i=1}^nRa_i$ is finitely generated. Following the answer of Aditya Dwivedi, $x\in(D^{-1}A)'$ if and only if $xa_i\in D^{-1}R$ for all $i\in[1,n]$.
($\Rightarrow$) Fixed some $i\in[1,n]$ and suppose $xa_i\in D^{-1}R$, say $xa_i=d_1^{-1}r_1$. Then $\forall\,d_2\in D$, $\forall\,r_2\in R$,
$$
xd_2^{-1}r_2a_i=d_2^{-1}xa_ir_2=d_2^{-1}d_1^{-1}r_1r_2=(d_1d_2)^{-1}r_1r_2\in D^{-1}R.
$$
Hence if $xa_i\in D^{-1}R$ for all $i\in[1,n]$ then $xD^{-1}A=xD^{-1}(\sum_{i=1}^nRa_i)\subseteq D^{-1}R$.
($\Leftarrow$) Let $x\in(D^{-1}A)'$ then $xa_i=x1^{-1}a_i\in xD^{-1}A\subseteq D^{-1}R$ for any $i\in[1,n]$.
Therefore we instead suppose $xa_i\in D^{-1}R$ for all $i\in[1,n]$, say there exist some fixed $d_i\in D$ and some $r_i\in R$ such that $xa_i=d_i^{-1}r_i$ for each $i$. Now $\forall\,a=\sum_{i=1}^ns_ia_i\in\sum_{i=1}^nRa_i=A$,
$$
\begin{aligned}
 xa
 &=x\sum_{i=1}^ns_ia_i
 \\&=\sum_{i=1}^ns_ixa_i
 \\&=\sum_{i=1}^ns_id_i^{-1}r_i
 \\&\begin{cases}
  \delta:=\prod_{j=1}^nd_j
  \\\delta_i:=\delta/d_i
 \end{cases}
 \\&=\delta^{-1}\sum_{i=1}^n\delta_is_ir_i
 \\&\in \delta^{-1}R,
\end{aligned}
$$
i.e., $\delta xa\in R$ for any $a\in A$. Note that the $d_i$'s are fixed (and only determined by the corresponding $a_i$'s) as required by assumption, so $\delta=\prod_{i=1}^nd_i$ is fixed, that is, $\delta$ is independent of the choice of distinct $a\in A$, so $\delta xA\subseteq R$. Let $y=\delta x$ then clearly $y\in A'$ and hence $x=y/\delta\in D^{-1}(A')$, namely $(D^{-1}A)^{\prime}\subseteq D^{-1}(A')$, as desired.

You correctly doubt the validity of the infinite product. However, your proof can be slightly modified to fix this problem. Observe that $x \in (A_P)'$ if and only if $xa_i \in R_P$ for all $i$. This reduces the problem to finitely many $d_i$'s.

Thank you, sir. Your hint does help in deed! I have posted an update in my question following your hint.
